# unicode not visible in notepad but visible in console

Tags: unicode, notepad

I was saving a file in notepad, and I got the warning message that the file contained unicode that wouldn't save correctly as ansi. I didn't see any characters that would be a problem, so I opened the file in the console and found these random-looking characters in the text. They aren't visible in notepad at all. Even the space they take up in the console isn't there in notepad. Below I've posted a screenshot of the text in notepad and in the console. What's going on?

notepad

[image: notepad]

console

[image: console]

Answer (score 2):

The characters being displayed at the console are the UTF-8 encoding for a [Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm), which would not be visible in Notepad or any other Unicode application. The console doesn't work with Unicode normally, it uses a code page (typically [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) to determine which character to display based on the bytes that are output. The UTF-8 encoding of the Zero Width Space is 3 bytes `\xe2\x80\x8b` so you see 3 characters on the console, doubled up because you have *two* Zero Width Spaces.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks so much. I need to sit down and really get familiar with the different kinds of encoding. Is there a relatively easy way to see the UTF-8 bytes in an editable format so I can edit them out? They are crashing my program.

Comment: @jana you could easily write a program to remove them. Just discard any byte that doesn't have a value between 0 and 127.

Comment: @jana: I use [WinVi](http://www.winvi.de/en/), which is a text editor that has a built-in hex editor, and supports UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings.  So you could load a UTF-8 file into it, switch to hex view, remove the offending bytes, and then save the file as UTF-8 again. You could even switch the text view to Ansi to make the UTF-8 bytes stand out visually, just like the console window does.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Thanks again. That looks like it would work.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks so much, I'll check out the editor.